# Como combinar queries? SQL

Tags: sql, select

Tengo 3 selects que me dan 3 respuestas de un total de **Count**'s que hago , pero quiero juntar los 3 en una sola respuesta para que me sea mas facil procesarla en mi front-end.
mis queries son

```
SELECT count(*) totalVigentes from clientes_ where estado = 'Vigente';
SELECT count(*) totalNoVigentes from clientes_ where estado = 'Deudor' || estado = 'Prorroga';
SELECT count(*) totalEnProrroga from clientes_ where estado = 'Prorroga';
```

pero lo que quiero es un query que englobe todo y que de resultado me de

```
//totalVigentes //  totalNoVigentes // totalEnProrroga
//  20           //  18              //  4
```

Alguien sabe como puedo hacer esto?

Comment: Para ese resultado usa case when

Comment: puedes agregar el script?

Comment: PAra que motor de base de datos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varias formas de hacerlo, aquí te propongo una, con subconsultas:

```
SELECT totalVigentes, totalNoVigentes, totalEnProrroga
FROM (
     SELECT count(*) totalVigentes from clientes_ where estado = 'Vigente'
     ) a
INNER JOIN (
     SELECT count(*) totalNoVigentes from clientes_ where estado = 'Deudor' || estado = 'Prorroga'
     ) b on 1=1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT count(*) totalEnProrroga from clientes_ where estado = 'Prorroga'
    ) c on 1=1
```

Comment: No es mejor un case (si supieras para que base de datos, obviamente) que esto, que va a recorrer la misma tabla 3 veces?

Comment: Por supuesto, pero a falta de conocer el tipo e base de datos, esta funciona, que yo sepa, con todas, o al menos las más habituales

Comment: Y si mejor primero preguntamos para que base de datos? digo, porque si no, acostumbramos a todo el mundo a preguntar mal...